# Ruby class and function

Tags: ruby, function, class

```
class Fixnum
 def previous
    return self-1
 end
end

return 6.previous
```

When I am executing this program I am getting the following error 
jdoodle.rb:8:in `': unexpected return (LocalJumpError).
I am using an online compiler for the program. Is there any mistake in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to `return` but you're not inside a method so Ruby doesn't know where you're expecting to return (or "jump") to. Perhaps you want to *display* the result:

```
puts 6.previous
```

In general, you'll see a [`LocalJumpError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/LocalJumpError.html) when you try to `yield` or `return` in a place where it doesn't make sense (i.e. if there is no block to `yield` to or method to `return` from).

Comment: Just in case there's any confusion,  is only referring to your second `return` statement. The first one is fine, but you would normally just write the last line of your method `self - 1`. That's because methods return the last value computed when there are no more statements to execute.